# Getting full Split array into a VBA variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Say I have a path in `Range("A1")` that looks like this:

```
/data/apps/server/
```

I would like to get the three elements into a variable. I've thought doing a `Split()` by the separator `/` I would get the full array:

```
Dim myElements()
myElements = Split(Range("A1").Value,"/")
'>>> EXPECTED: myElements is [data, apps, servers]
```

but I actually get a `Type mismatch` error on the line `myElements = Split(Range("A1").Value,"/")`. What does the `Split` function return? Does it actually return the array or it rather gives read-only access?

I would just like to get the array of the `Split` method without having to loop through them and build my own array, if possible of course.

Comment: You can't use `Dim elements()` .Change the name of your array and it will work.  Use `Dim Myelements`

Comment: @genespos: No it is not a reserved name :)

Comment: @genespos that's just a mock name I've used for sampling, but the real variable name is sure not a reserved one. But for sake of clarity I'm going to edit my question, thank you for the remark.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: Make that small change that I suggested and it will work :)

Comment: Sorry... :( the problem was in the "()"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `Dim elements()` to `Dim elements As Variant`

You need to declare it as a Variant.

**Explanation**:

The data in Excel cell can be anything. So use a `Variant`. In cases like below, you know it is a `String` so declare it like a `String`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myElements() As String
    Dim myString As String

    myString = "aaa/bbb/ccc"

    myElements = Split(myString, "/")

    Debug.Print myElements(0)
    Debug.Print myElements(1)
    Debug.Print myElements(2)
End Sub
```

`Split` returns a `String Array`. You may want to see [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/266289)

**Edit**: I have a feeling that I may confuse someone with my explanation so let me explain it a bit more.

`Dim myElements()` means "*Declare myElements as array of Variants*".
`Split` returns an array of Strings. Hence, the mismatch.

You can do either `Dim myElements` or `Dim myElements as Variant` or `Dim myElements() as String` to resolve the problem.

Here is why each one of these works:

1. `Dim myElements` and `Dim myElements as Variant`

   Both of these means that you declare myElements as Variant. Variants are special types, which can accept anything. As such, they can accept `array of strings` easily. However, variants have large memory overheads and should be avoided wherever possible.
2. `Dim myElements() as String`

   This means that you declare myElements as array of strings. Since this is the same type as what is returned by the `Split` function, it is accepted.

Ideally, if you know the return type of a function, you should specify the correct type for your variables.
So in this case, `Dim myElements() as String`   which is the same type returned from the `Split` funcition.

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddhart, it works as a charme. Would you mind explaining me why? I mean, what I get in the variable is not an array?

Comment: ++ Wish you were my teacher when I was learning VBA... LOL. You would have explained everything so nicely.. For FREE :D

Comment: Stop embarrassing me @PradeepKumar. :D

Comment: Heh Heh. No, Seriously, I like the way you take the time to explain. BTW Congrats on 70k ;)

Comment: Damn I didn't realize! Thanky Thanky :)